# Unable to open download save dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, .net-4.0, iis-6

Using the below code I am unable to show the open/save as file dialog:

```
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string link = context.Request.QueryString["Link"];
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(link);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(link);
            string fullPath = 
                 String.Format("{0}\\{1}",
                     context.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/"), 
                     fileName);

            if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                context.Response.AddHeader(
                    "Content-Length", 
                    new FileInfo(fullPath).Length.ToString());
                string contentType;
                switch (extension)
                {
                    default:
                        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                        break;
                }
                context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                context.Response.AddHeader(
                    "Content-Disposition", 
                    String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
                context.Response.WriteFile(fullPath, true);
                context.Response.Flush();       
            }
        }
```

I've tried to close the response, leave the response open, use `TrasmitFile()`, but I never get any dialog or any feed back whatsoever.  I've tried debugging it as well, but no exceptions are being thrown.  Tried in IE 7/8, and Chrome. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Below is the Fiddler output:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Length: 3813 Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Content-Disposition:
>   attachment;
>   filename=b1af9b34-28cc-4479-a056-8c55b41a5ece.txt
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 23
>   Dec 2010 21:51:58 GMT
>
> ```
> * Home
> * Hotels
> * Reviews
> * Community
> * Travel Guide
> * Travel Insurance
> * Contact us
> ```
>
> *** FIDDLER: RawDisplay truncated at 128 characters. Right-click to disable
>   truncation. ***

Comment: What does Fiddler say about the http connections?

Comment: What information from Fiddler do you think is important to paste?

Comment: How about an explanation for the down vote...

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I voted your question _up_ because I'd like to keep track of solving this particular issue in as many scripting languages as possible. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  There is actually no problem with the code I posted.  As you can see in the Fiddler output, the contents of the text file were successfully written to the response stream and the headers used were also correct.  The actual problem comes from how the actual http request was made.  I used a

> $.get(urlToGenericHandler);

request using jQuery.  The reason why specifically I am not able to download a file using AJAX or a callback model is beyond the scope of this answer.  See supported jQuery datatypes [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

***Anyways, I changed the call from using AJAX to using a basic post-back.***

Thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
contentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

to

```
contentType = "application/download";
```

**Update**: 
Try swapping the position of the header and content type

```
context.Response.AddHeader(
    "Content-Disposition", 
    String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
context.Response.AddHeader(
    "Content-Length", 
    new FileInfo(fullPath).Length.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Tried your suggestion, but same result.  There are no spaces in the filename as well.

Comment: @subt13: I've updated my answer with one last suggestion and then I'm out for now.