# Creating a CSV with c# that doesnt get "corrupted" by excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm generating the head of different CSV files so my users can see the format

```
var output = new MemoryStream()
var writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);
//this function gets the row depending of the enumerator name in this format a;b;c;d
var header = ModelosCsv.GetCsvByEnum("HeadRowFileLoad");
writer.WriteLine(header);
writer.Flush();
output.Position = 0;
return File(output, "application/csv", "format.csv");
```

The code is creating the CSV correctly but if they open the CSV with excel and save it, excel will overwrite all the ";" for triple spaces.
If I edit the result with notepad++ and put back the ";" excel won't do it again.

I have opened both archives with excel and clicked "save as", the first one (freshly generated by c#) is set as default as "text archive" the second one (edited by notepad++) is set as CSV.

Am I missing something code?
How could I do to stop excel messing up my archives?

Comment: where are you closing the memory stream.. ? why are you setting the output position..? not necessary...

Comment: Excel doesn't corrupt anything. Why don't you create a *real* Excel file with EPPlus?

Comment: As for Excel, it doesn't know what type of field, line, text,decimal, thousand separators your code uses. Nor can it ask, when you pass the file in the command line. It will use the *user's* locale settings, specifically the decimal, thousand and *list* separators to read the unknown file. When you open a CSV through the `Insert Data` dialog you get a preview that allows you to edit the settings if they appear wrong

Comment: What does `GetCsvByEnum` do? What does the generated text file look like? Excel won't replace `;` with triple spaces, even though it *isn't* the common field separator. It may treat it as text, displaying the entire row as a single field, if the user's locale uses `,` as the list separator, ie the US locale used by many developers

Comment: Im sorry , they are using CSV not real excel files and they are really stubborn about this (because the sometimes the csv files comes from other developers programs) so no EPPlus.

Comment: This is how one of the csv looks like referencia;direccion;localidad;provincia;cp;superficie;reference;tipoProducto

Comment: About closing the memory stream and setting position to 0 MethodMan if i dont do that the archive comes empty.

Comment: Are you sure you're not corrupting up the CSV file when you open it in Excel by not selecting the proper delimiter the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this answered question 
[Export to CSV using MVC, C# and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668906/export-to-csv-using-mvc-c-sharp-and-jquery)

```
        var header = ModelosCsv.GetCsvByEnum("HeadRowFileLoad");

        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(header), "application/csv", "format.csv");
```

This way Excel identifies the archive as CSV and editing wont break the format.