# jQuery delivery of a file with AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

If I have an AJAX call that returns, say, a CSV, how do I get the browser to prompt the user for a download?  Below, the ProductsExport will return the CSV in the success data.  I just need what I'd replace the // Deliver file to user line with...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Search/ProductsExport",
    data: $('#CustomerId').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {

        // Deliver file to user!!

    },
    error: function (xhr, textstatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error');
    }
})
```

My C# code on the back end looks like so:

```
var aFileContent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(export);
var aMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(aFileContent);
return File(aMemoryStream, "text/plain",
    string.Format("{0}.csv", CustomerId));
```

Comment: what's wrong with just linking to /Search/ProductsExport/<customerId> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot as far as I'm aware. You can't use ajax here as a file download.
YEs - its a support datatype as per jQuery but not for a file. You need to link to the file for a non ajax request either via a link or a jQuery get request.

See:
[Unable to open download save dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522590/unable-to-open-download-save-dialog)
and
"datatype" on 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to your problem is have an AJAX function return an actual URL that will download csv (similar to your C# backendcode). The client side will then launch the URL using window.open(url)

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be ajax?  Just build your url and do a window.location.href to execute your call.  All you seem to be passing it is a customerId, so that should be pretty easy.

Ajax operations are meant to allow a user to stay on the page while operations continue behind the scenes.  A file download will keep the user on the page and just download the file, so there's no benefit to using ajax in this siutation.  Something like this perhaps:

```
window.location.href = "/Search/ProductsExport?" + $.param($('CustomerId'))
```