# use ajxax when return type is stream: django

Tags: django, jquery, filestream

I need to use ajax in my form. but it seems that success function of $.ajax, doesn't support file. now i want to know how can i use ajax, when i want some time return form (when is not valid) and some time return stream to client for downloding (when form is valid). i've done googling and it seems that with $.get it might work. but i have form and i have to use post. Can anybody help me what's the way? thanks a lot.

In below function, stream doesn't work.

```
$('#sendButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var temp = $("#mainForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: temp,
            url: 'main/',
            success: function(data) {                
               ...
            }
        });
    });
```

my views.py:

```
def mainFunc(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
         form = mainForm(request.POST)
         if request.method == 'POST':
             if form.is_valid():
                 result = ""               
                 string_to_return = webservice._result
                 file_to_send = ContentFile(string_to_return)
                 response = HttpResponse(file_to_send,'application/x-gzip')
                 response['Content-Length'] = file_to_send.size
                 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;                  filename="somefile.tar.gz"'
                 return response
          else:
               form = mainForm()
          return render_to_response('main.html', RequestContext(request, {'form':form}))
     else:
          return render_to_response("ajax.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

You still can't return a file to an ajax request. The answer hasn't changed since [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13656831/44816)

What you *can* do is return the url for the download and redirect the user or pop open a new window/tab. Like this

```
$('#sendButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var temp = $("#mainForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: temp,
        url: 'main/',
        success: function(data) {
           # Option 1 - redirect
           window.location = data;
           # Option 2 - new window
           window.open(data, '_blank');
           window.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a bit confusing. What is 'data' exactly? I don't know much about stream. when we return stream, it means that we are returning file byte by byte? because in streaming, we didn't save file on the server, so what should be the file url? and if it has a url, we are returning stream (our file); so 'data' is stream. Now  how can i send url to success function while data is stream? really sorry for my silly question :">

Comment: You cannot stream the data in response to an ajax request. Data is the entire response to the ajax request, so in my example the response would _just_ be the url. You might want to return more than just the url, in which case you would need  to separate the file url from the rest of the data. Because the ajax request and file download request will be separate, you need to save the file _temporarily_ until the user has downloaded it. I know it is not the answer you want to hear, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: hmmm... suppose that this is url of the file which i want user to downoad: result = "media/mainFiles/main.tar.gz". if i return HttpResponse(result) in views, so what about returning stream? as i told i don't know much about stream. How is it returned? again sorry, you know i'm beginner...

Comment: The success function in my solution will take that url and open a new window which will ask the user the save the file.

Comment: yeah, but i think if i return url from view, it won't be stream any more. i mean i won't return stream any more...

Comment: Yes. Because you STILL can't return a file in response to an ajax request. It's not possible. Keep asking the same question and you'll keep getting the same response - I know it's not the answer you _want_, but it's the answer.

Comment: aha, so if i want to use ajax, there is no way except saving the file on the server and return its url. There is no way to use stream and ajax at the same time. 
By the way thanks a lot.